# Agregar nueva fila en data frame existente, abajo de filas ya creadas (Python)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, bucles

esperando que estén bien les indico esta duda. Soy nuevo programando y estoy aprendiendo dia a dia Python. Ahora estoy realizando un proyecto para aprender a hacer un programa que uno pueda agregar información desde python en un data frame, para luego volcar los registros en un archivo excel.

Por el momento todo bien hasta cuando quiero que se genere un registro debajo del ya existente (se genera siempre en la primera fila, quiero que pase a la segunda, tercera y así sucesivamente), he buscado información en stack overflow español e inglés y creo no encontrar algo que me ayude.

Me pueden ayudar?

Adjunto código, muchas gracias por su tiempo en leerme.

```
import pandas as pd

AgregarNuevo = input("Quiere agregar nuevo dato? (si/no): ")

while AgregarNuevo == "si":
    NuevaFecha = input("Agregar Fecha (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
    NuevaVenta = int(input("Agregar $ de Venta (00000): "))
    NuevaPublicidad = int(input("Agregar $ de Publicidad (00000): "))
    print("Se ha agregado ", NuevaVenta, "en venta y ", NuevaPublicidad,
          "en Publicidad", ", con fecha ", NuevaFecha)
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Fecha', 'Venta', 'Publicidad'))
    data.loc[len(data)] = [NuevaFecha, NuevaVenta, NuevaPublicidad]
    print(data)
    data.to_excel("ingresos.xlsx")
    AgregarNuevo = input("Quiere agregar nuevo dato? (si/no): ")
else:
    print("No se agregará nuevo dato")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `append` debería funcionar:

```
nuevodf = df.append(
    {'Fecha' : NuevaFecha , 'Venta' : NuevaVenta,'Publicidad': NuevaPublicidad},
    ignore_index=True
    )
```

o

```
nuevodf = df.append(
    pd.Series([NuevaFecha, NuevaVenta, NuevaPublicidad], index=df.columns),
    ignore_index=True
    )
```

`ignore_index`  hace que el index de la fila agregada sea el número siguiente después de la ultima fila.

Comment: Hola Camila, gracias por tu tiempo en ayudarme. Revisaré en el codigo y si tengo dudas te escribiré. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Camila, realicé lo que me indicaste pero entro en un loop que no paro (me vuelve a pedir fecha al momento de entregar todos los datos, debiera pedirme si quiero ingresar un nuevo dato), al parecer me falta un break y cuando lo coloco en el codigo, me arroja erro en el terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Debes crear el DataFrame fuera no dentro del ciclo, igualmente la converión a xlsx debería también ir fuera en principio:

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Fecha', 'Venta', 'Publicidad'))

while (input("Quiere agregar nuevo dato? (si/no): ").lower() == "si"):
    nueva_fecha = input("Agregar Fecha (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
    nueva_venta = int(input("Agregar $ de Venta (00000): "))
    nueva_publicidad = int(input("Agregar $ de Publicidad (00000): "))
    data.loc[len(data)] = (nueva_fecha, nueva_venta, nueva_publicidad)
    print((f"Se ha agregado {nueva_venta} en venta y {nueva_publicidad} "
           f"en publicidad con fecha {nueva_fecha}"))

print("No se agregará nuevo dato")    
data.to_excel("ingresos.xlsx")
```

Dos apuntes:

- Usar loc para agregar filas nuevas se conoce como "setting with enlargement" y funcionará siempre que el DataFrame tenga un índice numérico continuo, sin agujeros. Es decir, `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` y no `0, 3, 4, 6, 7`. En éste último caso puedes usar `pandas.DataFrame append` como muestran las otras respuestas.
- Tanto usar `loc` como `append` para agregar fila a fila es muy muy muy ineficiente. Aparte de la operación en si (conversión a Serie previa) hay que copiar el array interno al completo en memoria antes de poder agregar la fila. En un DF pequeño tal vez no tenga importancia, si se trabaja con muchos datos ésto puede ser insostenible. La solución es usar un diccionario o lista Python auxiliar e ir agregando filas a éste contenedor, cuando se termine de agregar se realiza en un solo paso la extensión del DataFrame.

---

```
import pandas as pd


temp_data = []
while (input("Quiere agregar nuevo dato? (si/no): ").lower() == "si"):
    nueva_fecha = input("Agregar Fecha (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
    nueva_venta = int(input("Agregar $ de Venta (00000): "))
    nueva_publicidad = int(input("Agregar $ de Publicidad (00000): "))
    temp_data.append(
        {'Fecha': nueva_fecha,
         'Venta': nueva_venta,
         'Publicidad': nueva_publicidad}
        )
    print((f"Se ha agregado {nueva_venta} en venta y {nueva_publicidad} "
           f"en publicidad con fecha {nueva_fecha}"))

print("No se agregará nuevo dato")
# Aquí podemos cargar un DF con datos previos (read_excel, read_csv, etc)
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Fecha', 'Venta', 'Publicidad'))
data = data.append(temp_data, ignore_index=True)
data.to_excel("ingresos.xlsx", index=False)
```

---

Considera evitar el uso de `CamelCase` para nombres de variables, módulos, métodos y funciones, por convención se reserva para nombres de clases solo. El resto usa `snake_case` (y `SNAKE_CASE` para constantes).

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado. He revisado y me funciona el while sin problemas. Además puse las variables según la norma que me indicaste. Lo que si, ahora con el codigo que tengo, no me agrega la informacion a el archivo excel. Voy a darle una vuelta mientras tanto. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Hola Edgard, despiste mio, en el último código se me paso agregar la linea que escribe el xlsx, puede que esa fuera la causa de lo que comentas. Corregido. Ten en cuenta que el xlsx se crea solo cuando el ciclo termine y todos los datos sean agregados y en el directorio de trabajo del script (no tiene por que ser el del propio script si se modifica durante la ejecución), si aún así te sigue fallando puedes editar la pregunta manteniendo lo que tengas y agrega el código actual, deja un comentario por aquí si lo haces para que me notifique el sistema.

Comment: Por otro lado, el código crea un archivo nuevo no agrega a la información anterior, si quieres ésto, comentamelo y te pongo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo..

Comment: Genial! en un comentario más arriba puse mi código final. Creo que por el momento está logrando su cometido, pero se puede mejorar (para que lo revises y me digas que tal). Lo que me gustaría saber como agregar la informacion en un excel existente, eso me llamó bastante la atención. Gracias por tu tiempo en leerme y ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

Agradezco cada uno de sus comentarios, ya que juntos me ayudaron bastante. Al final, realicé algunos cambios dentro del código, dentro de los cuales me permitieron realizar preguntas constantes hasta que se cambie la condición. Además, Estuve estudiando documentación de *pandas* donde pude mejorar algunas cosas.

Agrego el código para que puedan verlo, y en caso que exista alguna mejora, por favor, no duden en indicármelo.

De nuevo, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
import pandas as pd

excel = pd.read_excel('ingresos.xlsx', index_col=0)
print(excel)

while (input("Quiere agregar nuevo dato? (si/no): ").lower() == "si"):
    nueva_fecha = input("Agregar Fecha (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
    nueva_venta = int(input("Agregar $ de Venta (00000): "))
    nueva_publicidad = int(input("Agregar $ de Publicidad (00000): "))
    excel = excel.append(
        {'Fecha': nueva_fecha,
         'Venta': nueva_venta,
         'Publicidad': nueva_publicidad},
        ignore_index=True
        )
    print("Se ha agregado ", nueva_venta, "en venta y ", nueva_publicidad,
          "en Publicidad", ", con fecha ", nueva_fecha)
    print(excel)

print("No se agregará nuevo dato")
excel.to_excel("ingresos.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Claro. Leyendo tu código, se crea un dataframe nuevo cada vez, después de leer los datos. Ese DataFrame con un único valor es el que escribes todas las veces a tu hoja de Excel.

Yo lo cambiaría por algo así (pseudocódigo)

```
Inicializar DataFrame vacío
while True:
    pedir datos
    anexarlos al DataFrame vacío (append)
    ¿Quiere ingresar más datos?
        si: continuar
        no: salir del ciclo
Escribir el DataFrame al XLSX
```

---

```
# 1. Crear el DataFrame vacío
datos = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fecha', 'venta', 'publicidad']

# 2. Ciclo
while True:
    # 3. Pedir Datos
    NuevaFecha = input("Agregar Fecha (dd/mm/yyyy): ")
    NuevaVenta = int(input("Agregar $ de Venta (00000): "))
    NuevaPublicidad = int(input("Agregar $ de Publicidad (00000): "))
    print("Se ha agregado ", NuevaVenta, "en venta y ", NuevaPublicidad,
          "en Publicidad", ", con fecha ", NuevaFecha)
    datos = datos.append({"fecha": NuevaFecha, 'venta': NuevaVenta, 'publicidad': NuevaPublicidad)

    # 4. Preguntar si quiere más datos
    if input('Quiere más ') == 'no':
        break

pd.to_excel('ingresos.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Hola Luis, gracias por tu tiempo en responderme. Realizare los cambios inmediatamente y te comentaré como me fue. Muchas gracias